Do I have DDR3 or DDR3L Ram?


Above are the CPU-Z benchmarks please tell me I'm a newbie in hardware stuff.
I want to buy a new stick; that's why I need to know. I want to buy DDR3 if its DDR3 and DDR3L if it is DDR3L

M471B5173EB0-YK0 Questions are expected to be well researched.  The different between Low Voltage Memory DDR3 and DDR3 is well defined.

1.35 V means DDR3L.
Standard DDR3 runs on 1.5 V.
